# Permit Outlook user to send from email address in a different domain

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, outlook

We're using Outlook 2010 and Exchange 2007.

I have a user in our domain, jill@ourdomain.com, who needs to send out a message that should appear to come from an address in another domain.  The foreign address is an alias for a journal, say Eng_Journal_Submissions@ieee.org.

When she uses the From: pulldown in the Outlook composition window, she ultimately gets a bounce telling her "You are not allowed to send this message because you are trying to send on behalf of another sender without permission to do so."

It's fairly easy let somebody send as (or send on behalf of) another user in the same domain (e.g. linda_boss@ourdomain.com). But is there any way to let her appear to send from a foreign email address, using Outlook and Exchange?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if this was allowed most SPAM filters would deny the message.  Essentially the sender or the FROM portion of the message would not map back to the server who was sending it.  Moreover if ieee.org has an SPF record and your SMTP server is not covered by it it will get kicked pretty quickly not to mention you risk having your entire SMTP server and IP blacklisted.

You can always specify a Reply To address for each message in Outlook however.  I'm not sure if thats what you were trying to do or not.

Comment: As a work-around (which is perhaps the best solution), that's what we're doing now.  But I've been asked whether it's possible to do what I described. Thanks.

Comment: @David Not through the same client she connects to your domain with.  But what would stop her from installing a secondary client, or using webmail to connect to the other domain's mail server?

Comment: @HopelessN00b, IEEE provides an alias service that redirects mail to a real account; they don't provide a real email account.

Comment: @David  Oh.  Seems like an ironic approach to email for `The world's largest professional association for the advancement of technology.`  Any chance the user would see the humor in that?

Comment: @HopelessN00b, I imagine people who work at IEEE, and perhaps those with other affiliations, have bona fide email accounts there. The aliases are a service IEEE provides (as one example) to journal editors who would already have an email account with their home institution.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - IEEE provides the alias service to _all_ its members, e.g. I have one and use it when I want to look more serious to other EEs.